# calling a variable in find regex

Tags: bash

Is there a way to call a variable in the below manner?
in this case X=$(date --date=yesterday +%Y-%m-%d)

echo $X --> 2012-07-26

The below command works but even if the date is in 25 it considers. Means $X is considered as null and picks *. Is there a way specifically call that variable in below place $X.?

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*(/\asyncprocessor.log.'$X'*\|/Renewal.log.'$X'*\|/Scheduler.log.'$X'*\|/smsprocessor.log.'$X'*\|/Subscription.log.'$X'*).*' -exec ls -ltr {} \;

Comment: Also asked on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11685643/7552

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './\(asyncprocessor\|Renewal\|Scheduler\|smsprocessor\|Subscription\).log.'$X'.*' -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```